# How to "invert" an array in linear time functionally rather than procedurally?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, functional-programming

Say I have an array of integers `A` such that `A[i] = j`, and I want to "invert it"; that is, to create another array of integers `B` such that `B[j] = i`.

This is trivial to do procedurally in linear time in any language; here's a Python example:

```
def invert_procedurally(A):
    B = [None] * (max(A) + 1)
    for i, j in enumerate(A):
        B[j] = i
    return B
```

However, is there any way to do this ***functionally*** (as in functional programming, using `map`, `reduce`, or functions like those) in linear time?

The code might look something like this:

```
def invert_functionally(A):
    # We can't modify variables in FP; we can only return a value
    return map(???, A)                                       # What goes here?
```

If this is not possible, what is the best (most efficient) alternative when doing functional programming?

Comment: @aaronman He wants it inverted, not reversed.

Comment: It's obviously (mostly) possible, though the actual answer will vary according to what you actually consider “functional”.  What operations do you consider allowed or not?

Comment: Since many functional languages only, or, *preferably*, work with lists and tuples instead of associative arrays, the operation would be quite simple: a `map` in which each member of a list `[(a,b)]` is processed to return a list `[(b,a)]`.

Comment: @JB.: I'm not sure why it's ambiguous, it's a pretty well-known term... any expression that doesn't have side effects is functional and allowed. Which I guess more or less reduces to "no assignment statements". (Think of Haskell for example?)

Comment: @deceze: Using lists versus arrays isn't really a question of "preference" though, it depends on your usage pattern. If you need fast random access you can't use a list, no matter how much you prefer to use one. Even purely functional languages have separate array data types for this reason (again, as in the previous comment, [Haskell is an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays)).

Comment: Is the array a permutation of 0..length-1?

Comment: @Joni: Nope... but I'm curious; how would it help if it was?

Comment: consider `map(lambda x: [2,1,3,0].index(x), range(4))` Not the most efficient approach (quadratic complexity) but is "functional"

Comment: @Joni: That's linear time?

Comment: @Mehrdad if it isn't, then what would be an output for A = { 2, 3 } or A = { 1, 2, 2 }?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I'm assuming there are no collisions; if there are, then the value at the ambiguous spot is undefined. I updated the code to make it more clear that the arrays don't necessarily have to be the same size.

Comment: So given input [4] the output would be [-1,-1,-1,-1, 0]?

Comment: @Joni: Yeah, or anything else could be in place of the `-1`s.

Comment: @Mehrdad The usual suspects in functional programming definition would be: purity, immutability (non-obvious in a few cases because of the array). In Ocaml (functional not pure) the problem is trivial, you can update array cells in place, it's the reference that remains unassigned. In Haskell (pure) there's always the `ST` escape hatch (is that allowed?), failing that it's still easy to do in practice but hard to prove linearity. So in a word, there are solutions for all of those, but the question as is is too broad to select one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context are arrays mutable or immutable? Generally I'd expect the mutable case to be about as straightforward as your Python implementation, perhaps aside from a few wrinkles with types. I'll assume you're more interested in the immutable scenario.

This operation inverts the indices and elements, so it's also important to know something about what constitutes valid array indices and impose those same constraints on the elements. Haskell has a class for index constraints called [`Ix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html). Any `Ix` type is ordered and has a [`range`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#v%3arange) implementation to make an ordered list of indices ranging from one specified index to another. I think this Haskell implementation does what you want.

```
import Data.Array.IArray

invertArray :: (Ix x) => Array x x -> Array x x
invertArray arr = listArray (low,high) newElems
  where oldElems = elems arr
        newElems = indices arr
        low = minimum oldElems
        high = maximum oldElems
```

Under the hood [`listArray` uses `zipWith` and `range`](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/array.html) to associate indices in the specified range to the listed elements. That part ought to be linear time, and so is the one-time operation of extracting elements and indices from an array.

Whenever the sets of the input arrays indices and elements differ some elements will be `undefined`, which for better or worse blow up faster than Python's `None`. I believe you could overcome the `undefined` issue by implementing new `Ix a` instances over the Maybe monad, for instance.

Quick side-note: check out the `invPerm` example in the [Haskell 98 Library Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/array.html). It does something similar to `invertArray`, but assumes up front that input array's elements are a permutation of its indices.

Comment: I really like your answer. While it confirms what Ingo said (+1 to both of you!), I really like the fact that you gave an example and explained what's going on, along with its limitations, in detail. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: +1 as far as I am concerned, but @Mehrdad will ask you how `listArray` is implemented (which correpsonds to `fromTuples` in my answer)

Comment: @Ingo: Indeed, I would ask, but he already answered that question! *"Under the hood `listArray` uses `zipWith` and `range`..."*

Comment: @Ingo I like the simplicity of your answer, but it also left me wondering how `fromTuples` could be implemented, especially in linear time. After digging into the `Ix` class and the `listArray` implementation it's a bit clearer how it can be achieved. Granted, I didn't dig deeper than `MkArray`, so I can't yet *prove* linear time.

Comment: @JakeMitchell Well, it goes without saying that `fromTuples` would need 2 passes through the input list to get the needed size of the array first, allocate the array and then the second pass to actually fill it. In your solution you do essentially the same with minimum, maximum and listArray.

Comment: @Ingo That's suddenly apparent in hindsight--thanks for pointing it out. Arrays in Haskell are relatively new territory for me, so it was a good learning experience :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution needing `map`and 3 operations:

1. `toTuples` views an the array as a list of tuples `(i,e)` where `i` is the index and `e` the element in the array at that index.
2. `fromTuples` creates and loads an array from a list of tuples.
3. `swap` which takes a tuple `(a,b)` and returns `(b,a)`

Hence the solution would be (in Haskellish notation):

```
invert = fromTuples . map swap . toTuples
```

Comment: So you're basically assuming there exists a function called `fromTuples` that already does what we need, and hence the answer is to merely call it?

Comment: @Mehrdad If the functional language supports arrays at all, you can be quite sure that there will be functions to convert to and from lists. In addition, it is quite easy, like `toTuples array = [(i, array[i]) | i <- [0..length array -1]]`

Comment: Yes, `toTuples` *is* easy to implement, but *`fromTuples`*? It's not obvious to me how you could implement that in linear time within a functional language (hence the question). If I don't see a better answer I'll accept this, but it's not an interesting one if I assume there is already a library function that does what I need.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I am sorry, but in a pure functional language you can't update array elements destructively. Rather, there are library functions that do that, given a function from the index type to the element type. The most common case is just to create an array from some list. If you want destructive updates, there is probably no common "functional" idiom for it. Haskell may do it in the ST monad, F# directly, as it's impure.